# Python function for plotting distributions works with one DataFrame but not another - no output or error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, debugging, seaborn

I have the following python function to make graphs.

```
def plot_distributions(dataframe, title=None):
    # Set the style of seaborn
    sns.set(style="whitegrid")

    # Plotting distributions for each column
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))

    # Loop through each column and plot distribution
    for i, column in enumerate(dataframe.columns):
        plt.subplot(2, 3, i + 1)
        sns.histplot(dataframe[column], kde=True)

        # Add mean and median lines
        mean_value = dataframe[column].mean()
        median_value = dataframe[column].median()
        plt.axvline(mean_value, color='red', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, label=f'Mean: {mean_value:.2f}')
        plt.axvline(median_value, color='green', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2, label=f'Median: {median_value:.2f}')

        plt.title(column)
        plt.legend()

    # Set the title of the overall plot
    if title:
        plt.suptitle(title, y=1.02, size=16)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Then I have two dataframes, with the exact same six features and lenght but with different data.

```
plot_distributions(jaro_df)
```

```
plot_distributions(transformer_df)
```

The very weird thing is that using `jaro_df` works perfectly while `transformer_df` the script it is just loading and does not output anything, not even an error.
How is that possible? I tried both on google colab, jupyter notebook and vscode.

Comment: if you execute the plot_distributions in the reverse order, does it just work for the first call? i.e. `plot_distributions(transformer_df)` first and then `plot_distributions(jaro_df)`

Comment: No, it does not work even in reverse order. Saying jaro_df always works while transformer_df never works

Comment: you mention they are the same six features.... are they the same on a .info() basis?

Comment: I was expecting some kind of issue due to sns.histplot not getting the correct axis (and I was about to suggest using [matplotlib's axes interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/api_interfaces.html) and explicitly pass it as kwarg in sns.histplot). If that's not the case, I'd just try inspecting transformer_df feature distributions one by one (with and without KDE). Perhaps it could be getting stuck while attempting to calculate kde

Comment: actually if I run it row by row, when there is "sns.histplot(dataframe[column], kde=True)" it seems to stuck there. I tried also "kde=False" but it still get stuck. Any idea?

Comment: As far as I recall, in my experience (which may be outdated respective to current sns) a lot of data, "non-standard dtypes" such as dates / timedeltas  or extreme outliers may make histplot malfunction. Often times, it was due to getting stuck attempting to obtain the best bins. Try providing explicit bins for a reasonable range with something like `bins = np.linspace(start, end, num_bins+1edge)`

Comment: Got it! Identified the issue—both dataframes range from 0 to 1, but one had numerous decimals, causing a hiccup during bin creation. Appreciate the insightful intuition you provided! 

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad I could help. Now that you found the issue, I wonder if you could re-write / edit some parts of the question in order to be more accessible to somebody facing the same problem. Regards,

Comment: If you could provide the data in the two data frames, or better yet, produce a [mre] that would be really useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that both dataframes range from 0 to 1, but one had numerous decimals, causing a hiccup during bin creation